# What software can I used to open SGI images?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I have an image file which is in [sgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics_Image) format.

```
$ file image.sgi                        
image.sgi: SGI image data, RLE, 3-D, 280 x 200, 4 channels
```

How can I open it?. Tried using **eog** but it doesn't render them.

Are there any tools for this file format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick (package `imagemagick`) supports SGI files. You can use

```
display image.sgi
```

to view the image or

```
convert image.sgi image.jpeg
```

to convert it to a JPEG file.